# Typo3: Restrict editing page title by double click

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to remove the ability to edit the page title especially with double clicking it in the pagetree, for users which should be able to enable and disable pages?

When unchecking the "Edit Page" Property in the Access Module, they can't enable and disable the page, also when removing the pages table in the Accesslist "Tables (modify)" in the Backend Users Module.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, because it's an unusual case, but maybe it could be solved by configuring the `title` field as an [Excludefield](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Columns/Properties/Exclude.html).

But that would disallow editing this field at all - not only in the page tree.